Export in PDF issue in Angular using htm2canvas outside of jspdf pages
     <div id="content" #content>
    <div class="skill-view-head">
                <div>
                  <label for="emp-id">Emp ID: </label>
                  <span> {{employeeId}}</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <label for="emp-name">Emp Name: </label>
                  <span> {{empName}}</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <label for="doj">DOJ: </label>
                  <span> {{doj | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</span>
                </div>
              </div>
    <table class="skill-view-table certificate-table">
              <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Attributes</th>
                <th>Certificate Name</th>
              </tr>
              <tr *ngFor="let certificate of skillBonusdetails[0]?.getCertificatesTemp; let i = index">
                <td>{{ i + 1 }}</td>
                <td>{{ certificate.date | date:'MM/dd/yyyy' }}</td>
                <td>{{ certificate.type }}</td>
                <td>{{ certificate.certificateName }}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr *ngIf="skillBonusdetails[0]?.getCertificatesTemp?.length > 0" style="background-color: #fff;">
                <td colspan="3">Earned Points</td>
                <td>{{certificateEarnedPoints}}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr *ngIf="skillBonusdetails[0]?.getCertificatesTemp === null">
                <td colspan="4" class="text-center">No records available</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
    <div>
     <button (click)="onExportPdf(this.empName)" class="border-0 green-btn hide-export-btn">Export To PDF</button>

onExportPdf(EmpName) {
    this.loaderservice.display(true);
    const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'A4');
    const source = document.getElementById('content');
    const button = document.querySelector('.hide-export-btn') as HTMLElement;
    const button2 = document.querySelector('.hide-export-btn2') as HTMLElement;
    const button3 = document.querySelector('.hide-export-btn3') as HTMLElement;
    source.style.width = '800px';
    doc.setFontSize(8);
    doc.html(source, {
      callback: function (pdf) {
        //doc.output('dataurlnewwindow');
        doc.save(EmpName + ' Points Details.pdf');
        
      },
      html2canvas: {
        scale: 0.7
      }
    });
    this.loaderservice.display(false);
  }

I have this code to export table content in pdf format its working good but these is only one problem, when we export pdf then some content in footer is break between first and last page. See the attached image  highlighted issue between two pdf pages, can you please suggest how to fix this.

@KJ Thank you for your response, Can you please provide a code to fix this issue without using jspdf-autotable

can please provide a example to how we can do this.

Instead of export to PDF the html, you can use the array with the information.
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import autoTable from 'jspdf-autotable';


onExportPdf(EmpName: string) {
const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'A4');

// Add table
autoTable(doc, {
  head: headers,
  body: this.skillBonusdetails[0]?.getCertificatesTemp,
  startY: 48,
  showHead: 'firstPage',
  theme: 'striped',
  didDrawPage: (data) => {
    // Add page number
    const pageCount  = doc.getNumberOfPages();
    const pageSize   = doc.internal.pageSize;
    const pageHeight = pageSize.height ? pageSize.height : pageSize.getHeight();
    doc.setFontSize(10);
    doc.text(`Page ${pageCount}`, data.settings.margin.left, pageHeight - 10);
  }
});

// Save the PDF
doc.save(EmpName + ' Points Details.pdf');

}

Hi @Jose, My angular application version is 9 and I am unable to install jspdf-autotable NPM due to some dependency, can you provide a another method or solution to resolve this problem and thank you for the answer.
